# reading json wrapped status report from tinyG

Tags: python, regex, json

Im trying to write a regular expression to extract the data that is in bold.This is a json wrapped status report from the tinyG micro controller. Using pythons serial module i can request a status report and use the readline method to get it, but its in json format. the bold part happens to be in the format of a python dictionary. The bit at the end with the list of numbers following the "f" will be different for each status report.

I was wondering if there would be a way to extract the bold part and turn it from a string to a dictionary. I know there are modules out there for encoding and decoding json strings, but Im not sure if its overkill for a purpose this simple. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

string =  '{"r":{"sr":{**"line":0,"posx":-2.500,"posy":-6.500,"posz":-2.750,"posa":0.000,"feed":0.00,"vel":0.00,"unit":1,"coor":1,"dist":1,"frmo":0,"momo":0,"stat":3**},"f":[1,0,40,6206]}}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `JSON` module is more suitable for this situation.

```
string = '{"r":{"sr":{"line":0,"posx":-2.500,"posy":-6.500,"posz":-2.750,"posa":0.000,"feed":0.00,"vel":0.00,"unit":1,"coor":1,"dist":1,"frmo":0,"momo":0,"stat":3},"f":[1,0,40,6206]}}'

import json
q = json.loads(string)
print q['r']['sr']
```

The Result will be a dictionary.

```
{u'feed': 0.0, u'coor': 1, u'stat': 3, u'dist': 1, u'frmo': 0, u'posa': 0.0, u'posz': -2.75, u'posx': -2.5, u'posy': -6.5, u'momo': 0, u'line': 0, u'vel': 0.0, u'unit': 1}
```